# Wireless Problem on HP Pavilion G6

Tags: wireless, broadcom, hp-pavilion

I have a Broadcom wireless card in my laptop and the wireless is not working correctly. 
Right in front of the router the wireless signal is 70% and across the room it barely works and in another room it disconnects. I have the drivers and everything. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 64bit. It works perfectly in Windows 7. Can anyone help?

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1705]
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc Device [1002:9649]
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: ATI Technologies Inc Device [1002:1714]
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1709]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7804]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:12.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7807] (rev 11)
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd
00:12.2 USB Controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7808] (rev 11)
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:13.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7807] (rev 11)
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd
00:13.2 USB Controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7808] (rev 11)
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:780b] (rev 13)
    Kernel modules: i2c-piix4
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:780d] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:780e] (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:780f] (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:43a0]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:15.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:43a1]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:15.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:43a2]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1700] (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1701]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1702]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1703]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1704]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1718]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1716]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1719]
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl
08:00.0 Class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
```

Comment: It's very nice of you to mention you have a Broadcom wireless, but which model is it, and which driver is used??? Can you add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to the question.

Comment: I also have a HP Pavilion G6 which I am going to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on. Will I also be facing similar issues? Did you explicitly install those drivers? From some past experience I know that Broadcom hasn't been very friendly with Ubuntu, but Win7x64 sucks to the core, I can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

My HP laptop from that era had a R6168 wireless network card (shows via lspci), but often, the R6169 network drivers get loaded.  The R6169 will work, but depending on the router, the connection will struggle and you'll see the network go up and down a lot, killing throughput.  You'll get the same mismatch if you have the R8111 card.

Solution:  Install the [R6168 drivers from Realtek](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2).  They didn't get install automatically like they should have.